# XML elements not created

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Im new with lionq to XML and a little rusty with it. I am trying to create the below XML and save it as HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
<start>today</start>
<end>next week</end>
<Date>Some date</Date>
<customer>
....
.....
</customer>
</customers>
```

So far my code is

```
Dim XD As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><Customers></Customers>

For each c in mycustomers
MyXDocument.Root.Add(<Customer>.....</Customer>
Next
```

It gets the data and then creates the XML as required and saves it - this all works fine however i cant work out how to get these lines

```
<start>today</start>
<end>next week</end>
<Date>Some date</Date>
```

to be included in the XML with my code. I seem to be getting end tags mixed up or its just not happening. Could anyone advise?

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. Can you explain it in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the elements to your XML literal:

```
Dim XD As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <Customers>
                          <start>today</start>
                          <end>next week</end>
                          <Date>Some date</Date>
                       </Customers>
```

*Note: you're missing a `?` in your XML literal's XML declaration*

---

When running

```
For each c in Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    XD.Root.Add(<Customer><%= c %></Customer>)
Next
```

the XML looks like

```
<Customers>
  <start>today</start>
  <end>next week</end>
  <Date>Some date</Date>
  <Customer>0</Customer>
  <Customer>1</Customer>
  <Customer>2</Customer>
  <Customer>3</Customer>
  <Customer>4</Customer>
</Customers>
```

*Also note that first you use `XD` and later `MyXDocument`*

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XmlTextWriter in the following way:

```
  Dim xwriter As New XmlTextWriter(XmlFilePath, Encoding.UTF8)
        xwriter.WriteStartDocument()
        xwriter.WriteStartElement("customers")

        xwriter.WriteStartElement("start")
        xwriter.WriteString("today")
        xwriter.WriteEndElement()

        xwriter.WriteStartElement("end")
        xwriter.WriteString("next week")
        xwriter.WriteEndElement()

        xwriter.WriteStartElement("date")
        xwriter.WriteString("some date")
        xwriter.WriteEndElement()

        xwriter.WriteEndElement()
        xwriter.WriteEndDocument()
        xwriter.Close()
```

Not tested this - but you get the idea